# YTPlayerView not playing video with Youtube URL

Tags: ios, objective-c, youtube, ytplayerview

I am using YTPlayerView for playing embedded videos in my app. Everything works perfect with ID but video doesn't play with URL. Here is my code

```
-(IBAction)playVideo:(id)sender{
    self.playerView.delegate = self;
    self.playerView.hidden = false;
    [self.playerView loadVideoByURL:@"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KWTULSf29Ho" startSeconds:0 suggestedQuality:kYTPlaybackQualitySmall];
}
```

Comment: https://github.com/youtube/youtube-ios-player-helper/issues/168

Comment: The URL has to be in the format http://www.youtube.com/v/VIDEO_ID?version=3, your url was wrong.

Comment: This is normal url we will have from our user inputed. How can we achieve that specific format ?

Comment: No success :(
[self.playerView loadVideoByURL:@"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KWTULSf29Ho?version=3" startSeconds:0 suggestedQuality:kYTPlaybackQualitySmall];

Answer (score 0):

The URL has to be in the format youtube.com/v/VIDEO_ID?version=3, your url was wrong.

if you want to achieve the specific format, change your method which for responding user input url, appending `?version=3` with user input url.
[image]

check this，i think you forgot load the video into the player

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KWTULSf29Ho?version=3
Used this URL but no success.